# Converting text string column to date column in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the second column of a text file, which is a string, to a timestamp and write all values from the first file to another file (date converted)

```
import datetime
import time

infile = "datein.txt"
outfile = "dateout.txt"

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w")
for date in fin:
  date = ate = datetime.datetime(int(date.split(",")[1]).strptime("row[1]", "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
fout.write(date)
```

I get an error saying "TypeError: an integer is required"

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtOvA.png)

Comment: Post code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: I looked at your code and this is easily fixed, I suggest however you look around, as they are already answered all over SO. -1 for posting pictures and not code.

Comment: Hi anja9221! Don't let the down votes bum you out. Voting here is a mechanism for letting others assess the quality of a post. I wont down vote your question but the reason others have is because it isn't formatted in a way that easily let's us help you... namely, your code should be posted in the question so we can see it fast. There are other reasons why this question is downvoted and [you can learn why here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#stackoverflow). This site is all about learning. Improving your questions helps us all do that better. I hope you'll try again!

Answer (score 0):

The `integer` `datetime` is expecting is complaining because `date.split(",")[1])` contains a string, and even trying to cast it to an `integer` will return:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '01JAN2010:00:00:00'

Since that string resembles the date format you are passing to [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) (`"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"`), just use that string without any conversion, to get a `datetime` object, which then we cast the resulting `<datetime.datetime>` object to a string so the opened file can write it.

```
for date in fin.readlines()[1::]:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.split(",")[1], "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
    fout.write(str(d)+'\n')
```

gives us a `dateout.txt` with contents:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00
2012-01-01 01:00:00
2013-01-01 02:00:00
```

Hope that helps.